# Is it possible to pass a file path to setStyleSheet() in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, filepath, qtstylesheets

I found the following code in obs-studio:

[obs-studio/UI/obs-app.cpp](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/c354551484a10c6bed65c5531f91b1d045e46559/UI/obs-app.cpp#L733)

```
QString mpath = QString("file:///") + path.c_str();
setStyleSheet(mpath);
```

A file path preceded by `file:///` is passed directly to `setStyleSheet()`.

This usage is not mentioned in the official reference. However, obs-studio doesn't redefine this function, indicating that it is a Qt functionality.

Is this supposed to work? I tried it in my code but failed.

Comment: Surely somehow you have redefined it, do not complicate yourself with those ideas, for it to work you overwrite that method and add the reading of the file

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm confusing why obs-studio can do that? It doesn't redefine the function.

Comment: It tries to trace the code, that is, it looks for the ancestors of the class that uses that method. I think the question does not contribute much since you know how to generate that behavior, that is to override that method.

Comment: @eyllanesc I use grep to find all `setStyleSheet()`, and I'm sure obs-studio doesn't redefine the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Qt documentation there is no indication of supporting any URL to be passed as an argument to `setStyleSheet()`. Furthermore, if you look at the [definition of QApplication::setStyleSheet](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qapplication.cpp#n1036), there is no URL handling.

The stylesheet is proxied by a `QStyleSheetStyle` object. Within that object, you will find that the string ends up at [this method of the CSS parser](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/text/qcssparser.cpp#n2186). The functionality to read a file is there indeed.

The logic to treat the string's content as a file path instead of stylesheet markup [can be found here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp#n1576). The `file:///` part, if present, is removed and the string is then understood to be a path.

However to me it seems to be an undocumented feature and therefore better be avoided.